# ESP32. The best environment for creating large projects

Tags: reactjs, registry, esp32, micropython, arduino-esp32

**Hello :)**

I created a project which is about scheduling tasks etc. I created it using the Arduino.h library for ESP32 and I'm going to rebuild it (create it from scratch, because I don't like the file structure and the code itself). The current project, ready to be sent, takes up almost 90% of the space on ESP32 and 1.5MB configuration data and website files on SPIFFS partition.

There are a couple of frameworks for developing ESP32 applications, including MicroPython only the problem is that when using MicroPython on the website it is shown that first the MicroPython interpreter is loaded onto the board and then the .py files that are compiled on the board are put on the spiffs partition. But in my case this solution makes no sense because MicroPython on the board provides a lot of libraries that are already like that and I will not use them so they only take up space.

Is it possible to create an application and compile it on the computer and to load the already compiled application on the board so that you do not have to load the compiler on the board? Of course, using Python (MicroPython)

---

I also saw something like registers code for arduino on the Internet, something like that

```
int main(void){
  //setup code that only runs once
  DDRD = 0b00000100; // set pin 2 as output
  DDRD |= (1<<DDD3); // set pin 8 as output
  
  while(1){
    //code that loops forever

    PORTD = 0b00000100;
    _delay_ms(1000);
    PORTD = 0b00000000;
    _delay_ms(1000);
    PORTD |= (1<<PORTD3);
    _delay_ms(1000);
    PORTD &= ~(1<<PORTD3);
    _delay_ms(1000);
  }
}
```

This is a simple blink code that instead of using the pre-made functions pinMode, digitalWrite etc. uses variables (addresses) and works the same as the digitalWrite function. Only that is a big difference because using the Arduino.h library and its functions, an arduino application takes up a lot more space than using direct registers.
And I wonder if there is something similar on ESP32, or is it possible to reduce the size of the code with something similar?

---

As for frameworks, which framework will be the best in terms of the amount of memory space used?

Is web development with ReactJS for use in an ESP32 board project worthwhile in terms of optimizing the size of the entire web page to fit on the SPIFFS partition? However, is the best way to create a website without using any frameworks? It is also about the convenience of creating pages and possibilities?

Comment: For MicroPython the simple answer in principle is yes, you can build your own custom MicroPython firmware without components that you don't need, and you can include your own code in the build in the form of 'frozen' modules. The best place to go for more information is probably the [MicroPython forum](https://forum.micropython.org/).

Comment: Can you tell us more about the specific esp32 module? I don’t have any experience with upython, but maybe it’s a nice moment to check c/c++ and Espressifs esp-ide on vscode. Check learnesp32.com for a nice (paid, low fee) step in course.

Comment: You can always go bare metal by coding using direct register access. However, if your code took up 90% of ESP32 memory (I assumed that you are talking about RAM instead of Flash), the chances are you are using a lot of libraries and strings that aren't keep in the flash and/or a combination of both. When going bare metal, you may need to write your own drivers and libraries, so you need to know what caused the high usage of memory first.

Comment: BTW, the react question is irrelevant. If you are serious of creating a web server serving webpage, you might want to consider to get a Linux box like Raspberry Pi with a proper OS, instead of using an ESP32(which is a MCU with limited ram and flash memory and no OS).

Comment: @hcheung The computer cannot be because it is too expensive and, secondly, it is a system that will be in the garden for watering plants

Comment: @hcheung Regarding 90% of consumption, it is about the consumption of flash memory, partitions per program.

And when it comes to direct references to memory, I would like to, but I did not find any entries regarding memory in ESP32 only for arduino.

Comment: @nekomatic I use a dozen or so modules in the project, when it comes to python, I did not use some specific ones when creating the project, but you can guess that the micropython modules are on the board because the code is compiled on the board and not on the computer

Comment: There are 4MB, 8MB and even 16MB ESP32 modules that you can pick, of course many of the ESP32 development board come with 4MB ones.

Comment: A Raspberry Pi Zero costs $5 and is sufficient for your application. On the another note, a garden watering control app took 90% flash plus 1.5MHz SPIFFS is a lot.

Comment: @hcheung I know that there are boards with more flash memory, but I do not have one, and I have not seen the Raspberry Pi Zero with so much memory, but from what I saw, it does not have flash memory, only ram but it has an sd slot

Comment: Raspberry Pi is a real computer, just like your PC, it is not a MCU. For computer, programs are loaded from the storage media into the ram for execution, so it doesn't need flash. For MCU(e.g. ESP32), program is executed in flash, the ram is only for holding the variables, the stack and heap required for executing the program. Anyway, I already provided the answers to your question of "can I program ESP32 with register access"? as well as the pros and cons and the hint of taking a profiling on why your code took up some much flash. And also provided the alternatives for considerations